# Getting npm error when installing js-yaml module

Tags: typescript, npm, npm-install

I want to use js-yaml module in my typescript code as below.

```
const yaml = require('js-yaml');

let fileContents = fs.readFileSync('lib/deploy_config.yaml', 'utf8');
let data = yaml.load(fileContents);
```

When I am installing js-yaml module using **npm install js-yaml --save** command, I am getting below error.

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@amzn%2fcdk-bones - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@amzn/cdk-bones@^4.0.7' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/venbilla/.npm/_logs/2023-02-01T07_12_53_402Z-debug-0.log
```

I have tried various methods like changing configuration as below. but it is not working
**npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org**